# Traffic Manager applies to both Azure Global and Azure China

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager, azure-china

We have a web app deployed to Azure App Service in Azure Global West US region. It works very well for US users. But, for Chinese mainland users, they are suffering low repsonses due to high latency. 
The idea comes to my mind is to deploy the same app to Azure China, and use Traffic Manager to route the traffic to Azure China instance for Chinese users. 
I know that Azure China is physically iosolated with Azure Global. I don't know whether the Traffic Manager is able to work in this case. 
Will it work? If yes, how? If no, any other solution to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution should work as long as your website is accessible from the internet, that way TM can probe them:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-traffic-manager-in-azure-in-china/